# JUnit / TestNG execute @BeforeXXX method before all tests having the same parameter

Tags: unit-testing, junit, testng, parameterized-tests

I have the following problem:

I have a parameterized test

- it has a list of parameters
- it has several test methods
- test methods need a set up for each parameter

More detailed:

- for each file in list [...]
- parse file to several tables in db - [setUp]
- read data from tables - [setUp]
- and test data from each table in separate test - [tests]

I would like to execute setUp method and tests in such order

1. initialize parameters
2. for first parameter

   - execute setUp method with first parameter
   - execute all tests methods with first parameter
3. for second parameter

   - execute setUp method with second parameter
   - execute all tests methods with second parameter
4. ...

I tried JUnit and TestNG to do this and didn't find the solution. I would like to know if anyone knows how to do it.

I found a workaround for this in JUnit - place setUp and all test in one test method, and use ErrorCollector to make sure all check will be executed. But I don't like it because this way report is less clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this feature is in process of implementation in JUnit, but stalling.
https://github.com/junit-team/junit/pull/605